# Pandas groupby and aggregate on some operation between columns

Tags: pandas, aggregate

I'm an `R` and `data.table`user trying to use more `Python` and `pandas`, and when I want to do the following in `pandas`, I get so frustrated because there does not seem to be an easy way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'b': [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1], 'c': [10, 9, 10, 22], 'd': [2, 3, 3, 1]})
```

In `R` if I wanted to sum the product of `b` and `c` and divide on the sum of `d`, grouped on `a`, I would just do:

```
df[, sum(b*c)/sum(d), by=a]
```

, but this seems hard for me to do elegantly in `pandas`. I mean no offence, please don't hate me, it is probably just me not understanding `pandas` yet.

Solution thus far:

```
df[["b", "c"]].prod(axis=1).groupby(df["a"]).sum()/df.groupby("a").d.sum()
```

Comment: For sure, pandas is often more verbose than R, I fully agree. I think it originates from the fact that R was design for statistics while pandas was built on top of a generic programming language. There are some pandas extensions to mimic how R works though…

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Interesting, do you have any extensions to recommend? I was not looking to start an R vs Python thing, just so that is said. I was merely curious!

Comment: you can find useful references in the [comparison with R](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/comparison/comparison_with_r.html) page of pandas' documentation

Comment: Have a look at pydatatable, it allows for some concise expressions. Note that it is still growing, and as such is not as feature rich as pandas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have done the same as you did.

If you want you can also use `groupby.apply`:

```
df.groupby('a').apply(lambda g: (g['b']*g['c']).sum()/g['d'].sum())
```

output:

```
a
1    0.76
2    1.05
dtype: float64
```

Comment: thank you! I still think it is quite a lot of code though, although it is elegantly written!

Comment: @BerthrandEros the `eval` and `query` functions are nice to have short code, but the `sum` wouldn't be supported unfortunately…

Answer (score 0):

If performance is important, avoid `groupby.apply` - create helper column `new`, aggregate both and last divide both columns:

```
s = (df.assign(new = df[["b", "c"]].prod(axis=1))
       .groupby("a")[['new','d']]
       .sum()
       .eval('new / d'))
print (s)
a
1    0.76
2    1.05
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I think OP wanted to discuss concise code. Anyway, if performance is important, the original approach is likely more efficient. Also, a quick test on 40k rows shows this "assign" approach to be 2 times slower than `groupby.apply` ;)

Comment: @mozway exactly, concise code, not having to write all this stuff when doing data wrangling

Comment: @mozway - 40krows with 2 groups - 20k + 20k values?

Comment: @mozway - How looks quick test?

Comment: @jezrael I haven't tested further as the goal here is concise code

Comment: @mozway - ya, it is testing trap using `concat` for 2 groups. So quick test is not good idea use here.

Comment: probably, this was just on a side remark, but anyway the original approach is likely the fastest no?

Comment: @mozway - not tested, no idea. there are 2 times groupby, it should be reason for bottleneck, but without good testing (not quick test with 20k groups) hard to know.